# R : logical operation with numeric vectors in R

Tags: r

Can someone please explain me the difference between these two operations ?

**Operation 1**

```
> frac <- seq(0, 100, by = 5);
> frac == 30
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[15] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

**Operation 2**

```
> frac2 <- seq(0.0, 1.0, by = 0.05);
> frac2 == .30
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[15] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Who will find the best duplicate first...?

Comment: ya i dont know where a duplicate is so ill just say that OP should read the R inferno. http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Comment: @Dason Ha ha! I might have beaten you if I hadn't tried to be funny first. You win!

Comment: It's also in the R-FAQ. Lots of good nuggets in section 7 of the FAQ.